# Averaging every two consecutive index values(every 2min) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I know there are similar questions that have already been answered. However, I can't seem to troubleshoot why none of the solutions are working for me.
My sample dataset:

```
   TimeStamp      340          341         342          
   10:27:00     1.953036     2.110234     1.981548      
   10:28:00     1.973408     2.046361     1.806923        
   10:29:00     0.000000     0.000000     0.014881        
   10:30:00     2.567976     3.169928     3.479591
```

I want to find the mean of the data every two minutes for each column. While df.groupby promises a neat solution, it makes my TimeStamp column disappear for some reason. the help is greatly appreciated.

Expected output:

```
TimeStamp       340          341          342      
10:27:30     1.963222     2.078298     1.894235            
10:29:30     1.283988     1.584964     1.747236
```

Attempted code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    path = '/Users/username/Desktop/Model/'
    file1 = 'filename.csv'

    df = pd.read_csv(path + file1, skipinitialspace = True)

    df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['TimeStamp'])
    df['TimeStamp'] = df['TimeStamp'].dt.floor('min')
    df.set_index('TimeStamp')
    rowF = len(df['TimeStamp'])

    # Average every two min
    newdf = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))//2).mean()
    print(newdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the time as index:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_timedelta(df.TimeStamp), inplace=True)
```

And then use `resample` and aggregate every two minutes:

```
 df.resample("2min").mean().reset_index()

#   TimeStamp       340       341       342
#0   10:27:00  1.963222  2.078298  1.894235
#1   10:29:00  1.283988  1.584964  1.747236
#2   10:31:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Drop the last observation with `iloc`:

```
df.resample("2min").mean().reset_index().iloc[:-1]

#   TimeStamp       340       341       342
#0   10:27:00  1.963222  2.078298  1.894235
#1   10:29:00  1.283988  1.584964  1.747236
```

---

If you prefer to shift the `TimeStamp` by 30 seconds:

```
(df.resample("2min").mean().reset_index()
   .assign(TimeStamp = lambda x: x.TimeStamp + pd.Timedelta('30 seconds'))
   .iloc[:-1])

#   TimeStamp       340       341       342
#0   10:27:30  1.963222  2.078298  1.894235
#1   10:29:30  1.283988  1.584964  1.747236
```